# Name for the 1-2-4 chord

Tags: chords, chord-theory

Is there a name for the chord 1-2-4?

For instance, it's appearing in Schubert's Sonata D959 in the second bar: A-B-D.

Comment: An inversion of Bm7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measure in question:

[image: Schubert D959 beginning]

B minor 7th. It's lacking the 5th (F♯), but that's okay, the 5th doesn't add much color. If you add it in to the right hand, you'll notice that it doesn't change the sound much.

Comment: It's just B minor with pedal A's. A seventh chord at Schubert's time would need the seventh to resolve. The thirds in the passage [AC#] [BD] [C#E] [DF#] [EG] serve as independent voices against the pedal A's.